# Last DDL performed on a table Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, ddl, toad

is there a way to know the last ddl performed on a table? I dont want to know the time but the ddl sentence (create, alter, drop).

The issue: When I insert a row on table, TOAD doesnt response and the db cant be used by other users, gets locked.
After killing the toad process with the task manager, I reopen it and says that the last ddl time of the table is like 4 second ago and the row is not inserted. This issue happens just with that table.

I know that an insert is a DML sentence so i dont know why the last ddl time gets updated.

PS: English isn't my first lenguage, i hope you can understand the text.-

Comment: What exactly is the statement you were using? I don't see the relation between DDL and the "row is not inserted"? What kind of insert did you expect when you ran a DDL statement?

Comment: Actually, I am not even using an insert sentence. I am using the schema browser to insert a row

Comment: Again: what is the SQL statement you are running?

Comment: TOAD is your problem ... (probably) ... it probably does some sort of explicit (under the bonnet)  lock on the table which I think is logged as DDL.
Have you tried doing a simple INSERT is sqlplus to see if you get the same result? And also, are you committing after the INSERT ... I think TOAD connects each windows as a separate session, so if you INSERT in one window (be it schema browser or whatever), then that window will have the lock, preventing other windows from doing updates to that row/table (depending on the exact lock).

Comment: To add answer to your question about what the DDL is - try looking at V$SQL and (if you have the access) dba_hist_sqltext.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the last_ddl_time column in ALL_OBJECTS table.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1102.htm

Comment: This doesn't answer the chap's question - he is asking what the last DDL is, not when ... which he already seems to know.